# Visual Studio Installer Project - Script error

Tags: c#, vbscript, visual-studio-2015, installation, windows-installer

I'm creating my first installer through the built-in deployment project. My application uses the HTTPListener library which requires Admin privileges. To get around this I've read several posts saying you need to add the URL through netsh. So I created a basic vbs script to add the permissions to be ran during the install of the applications so admin privileges aren't actually required to run the application, only install it. The problem is when i try to include the script in the install project, build the msi and run it i get the following error:

[image]

My current vbs script is:

```
Set oshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oshell.run "cmd.exe /C netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1234/localhost/ user=everyone && netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1234/ user=everyone"
```

The current project setup with custom actions looks as follows:
[image]

I've tried putting the vbs script in both the "install" and "commit" actions with no success.

Any aid would be immensely appreciated. It could just be something obvious with the vbs file I'm missing too as I haven't done vbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use WScript.CreateObject in a custom action. The WScript object is an object model supplied when your script is run with Windows Script Host, and you are not in that environment. I don't think you even need it - just try CreateObject.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!